# upgrading to AngularJS 1.5 slows down karma + jasmine + phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to upgrade an AngularJS 1.3 app to 1.5.  After doing so, the first thing I found is that my karma test suite runs ridiculously slow.  I am using:  node 5.7.0, phantomjs 2.1.1, and karma 0.12.35

My karma config looks like:

```
basePath: '../../..',
port: 9876,
frameworks: ['jasmine'],
logLevel: 'debug',
files: [
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/angular.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/lodash.min.js',

  'vendor/assets/javascripts/jwplayer.js',
  'vendor/assets/javascripts/**/*.js',

  'app/assets/javascripts/shared/shared.js',
  'app/assets/javascripts/myapp/my_app.js',
  'app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js',

  'spec/javascripts/support/*.js',
  'spec/javascripts/**/*_spec.js',

  {pattern: 'spec/javascripts/fixtures/**/*', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
],
proxies: {
  '/picture.jpg': '/base/spec/javascripts/fixtures/assets/picture.jpg',
},
exclude: [
  'spec/javascripts/support/karma_config.js',
],
preprocessors: {},
reporters: ['dots'],
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
```

My test suite which took around 5 seconds to run previously with AngularJS 1.3, is now taking over 10 minutes. I set the log level to debug, hoping to get some insight into what it's doing during the slowness, however there is no output other than the dots during the test run, and occasionally when it hits image proxies.  Other than that...  It's like the tests themselves are just taking forever to run.

An example of what one of my javascript tests might look like:

```
describe('SomeController', function () {
  beforeEach(module('myAppsControllers'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    var controller = $injector.get('$controller');

    this.scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    this.http = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

    this.controller = controller('SomeController', {
      $scope: this.scope,
      viewModel: {
        items: ['foo', 'bar']
      },
    });
  }));

  it('sets the heading', function () {
    expect(this.scope.heading).toEqual('hello foo, bar');
  });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why AngularJS 1.5 would cause everything to slow down this bad, and how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: We also upgraded to 1.5, but there are no performance issues with karma/jasmine/phantomjs using karma-chrome-launcher. I guess you implemented some code meanwhile you upgraded.

Comment: @CodeNashor can you share your package.json so I can see what versions of karma and everything you are using?